# Is it possible to define a new mathematical operator in python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to define my own mathematical operator?

Like the introduction of the new `@` in [PEP-465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) for matrix multiplication or `//` for [integer division](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/#semantics-of-floor-division).

Something like

```
a ! b -> a / (a + b)
```

Comment: Adding those new operators required changes to the language. So in theory you can submit a PEP and get it accepted, implemented, and released in a future version of Python.

Comment: Use a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the predefined operator that has not been implemented for integers.

For example this one : `@ (matmul)`

You cannot use `!` character as it is not in this [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return self / (self + other)
```

Then you can do :

```
a = MyInt(1)
b = MyInt(2)
print(a @ b)
```

Will print (0.33333333)